# Nokogiri is returning odd hrefs for links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am using `nokogiri (~> 1.8.4)` to try to scrape all links on a page. However, it is returning weirdly formatted strings.

Here's my code:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

def all_links
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=sergey+facebook"))
  links = doc.css('a')
  hrefs = links.map {|link| link.attribute('href').to_s}.uniq.sort.delete_if {|href| href.empty?}
  hrefs
end
```

Sample output:

```
/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fen%2Dgb.facebook.com%2Fpublic%2FSergey%2DKozhanov
```

The links on that page don't have hrefs like that:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I tried using xpaths too and got the same result.

Comment: It looks like Duck Duck Go is returning an internal link which will redirect to an external link when clicked. Maybe it has detected Nokogiri has no JavaScript, where a real web browser uses JavaScript to ping DDG each time you click a link. Try parsing the URI and extracting the 'uddg' parameter for the external link.

Comment: Please, don't post pictures of your data. Post the *actual* data. This is a programming site, not a photography site. We want to copy&paste&debug&read your data, not critique its use of color and composition. Case in point: on my old laptop with my screen resolution, all I see is two red arrows pointing to a blob that may or may not be text that is actually relevant to the question but is impossible to read.

Answer (score 0):

After reading my comment, now use `parts = href.split('?')` and `CGI.parse(parts.last)['ubbg']` to get to the target URI.

Comment: ended up ditching ruby and going with JS + puppeteer for a headless browser

Comment: Right - a real browser tells the website it has JavaScript, so you get the real HREF and not the self-directing version...